# NGINX basic auth bypass IP address OR user agent

Tags: nginx

How to set up bypass in Basic Authentication by IP address or user agent in NGINX. If I set it like this:

```
map $http_user_agent $auth {
    default on;
    "~curl" "off";
}

server  {
.......
satisfy any;
allow 1.2.3.4;
allow 5.6.7.8;
deny all;
auth_basic $auth;
auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;
.....
}
```

Then when I enter from an address other than the whitelist with user agent curl, then I get 403.

Answer (score 0):

Disabling `auth_basic` likely removes it from the `satisfy` rather than making it true.

You can achieve what you are attempting by adding yet another authorization scheme, [auth_request](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_auth_request_module.html).

For example:

```
map $http_user_agent $auth {
    "~curl"  1;
}

server {
    ...

    satisfy any;

    allow 1.2.3.4;
    allow 5.6.7.8;
    deny all;

    auth_basic "Password protected";
    auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;

    auth_request /auth;
    location = /auth {
        internal;
        if ($auth) { return 200; }
        return 401;
    }

    ...
}
```